# Given a format string (String.format()/Formatter) is there an easy way to get the expected argument types?

Tags: java, android, formatter

I'm working on some unit tests for localization in our Android app. Right now my unit test checks all of our different format strings for all of our different locales to make sure the translators didn't mess them up (which they tend to do). Basically I'm making sure that calling String.format() won't throw a format exception.

The only downside is I need to manually add every string to the test. I'm working on a replacement test that uses reflection to find every string in R.string. Getting the strings isn't a problem, but is there any easy way to determine the number and types of arguments a format string expects?

String.format() doesn't complain if you pass it too many arguments so I could probably just pass a big array of Integers (which could get unboxed to %d or toString()'ed to %s) and look for format exceptions. Still, it would be a little nicer if I could pass the correct types of arguments in the correct amounts :)

Comment: FindBugs has an useful checker for this case.

Comment: The format strings are all defined in various Android XML files so I don't think FindBugs could help me in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, I think the method of checking for an `Exception` is the best one you'll come across without using your own fully-fledged parser.

If you are seriously interested in writing a code to find all the elements (that will be come arguments) from [the `format(...)` method of `Formatter.java`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Formatter.java) (I can't find an anchor, so you just have to control+f `format(Lo` and you'll find it). This code is also available in the SDK under `sources\android-16\java\util`, in the private method `doFormat`.

It's actually a relatively simple code once you learn the methods it uses to find each section and parse it. I think with a bit of work, and perhaps a bit of copy-paste from `Formatter`, you could set up your very own code that would simply find the elements of the `String`, instead of substituting them.

Comment: Thanks. I was afraid that would be the only way to do it. I think implementing my own parser based on Formatter would be overkill for the simple unit test I'm working on, so I'm going to stick with checking for exceptions. I'm really only interested in making sure the app doesn't crash in some random language in production.

Comment: It should be okay as long as all your locales have the strings provided to them. I would just suggest choosing a default string in the event that some string throws an exception.

Comment: We have all of the strings in strings.xml so if one's missing for a given locale it will just fall back to that value. But choosing a default string when an exception is thrown is a really good idea. Thanks!